# newsletter background images not showing in outlook w10 app

Tags: outlook, html-email, newsletter

Before asking I have tried all possibles solutions posted here but I can't make this work. Also i am not sure if its working regular outlook or I just have the issue on the w10 mail app.

This is the code I am using.

```
<td background="image.jpg" bgcolor="#e7e7e9" width="299" height="274" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:299px;height:274px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="image" color="#e7e7e9" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Any guidelines would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: For clarity sake, Microsoft's Outlook product is not the same as their Windows 10 Email App, so the post title is a misnomer.

Answer (score 3):

From searching the web, I found and adapted a VML-based solution that is also backward compatible for Outlook.

Note: This is only for background images embedded within a table-cell. I haven't attempted this for a full-body email background image yet. Once I do, I'll update this post.

**Background Info (no pun intended)**

The previous VML-based hack used to embed background images in Outlook emails (versions 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016) doesn't work for the Windows 10 Email App (Win10 app). For reference, you can see that solution at [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/).

Microsoft continues the use of Microsoft Word as its HTML rendering engine, but I'm guessing they made changes to Win10 app's rendering engine that affected its VML support.

Note: My example uses an image with dimensions 640x254. Note: I have a feeling the XML namespace is duplicated, but since it works, I don't want to mess with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Your Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tr><td height="254" background="http://yourimagepath.jpg" style="background:url(http://yourimagepath.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style="behavior:url(#default#VML);position:absolute;width:640px;height:254px;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1" src="http://yourimagepath.jpg"/>
    <![endif]-->
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I highlighted the specific things I added or are needed to ensure it works.

[image]

*Adapted from*:

- Alex Robinson's comment from [Windows 10 Mail Email Rendering Support + Quirks](https://litmus.com/blog/windows-10-mail-email-rendering-support).
- Ruth Boon's comment from [Windows 10 Mail: Bulletproof Background/Buttons Broken](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4176-windows-10-mail-bulletproof-background-buttons-broken).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Tested on Litmus: Windows 10 mail, Outlook 2016, 2013, 2010, 2007 and 2003.

Comment: Glad it did, but something to note: I just discovered that this only works if the table/td containing the background image does not have a background color defined. I'm trying to resolve that now on my downtime. I'm guessing that it has to do with the negative z-index - the background image will stack underneath the "layer" containing the background color, hence why it doesn't display.

Comment: what path i have to use in this behavior:url(#default#VML)

Comment: @user9437856 no update needed; keep as is.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is support for VML in W10 app, backgrounds and 'bulletproof buttons' through VML no longer work. I have not found a good technical explanation on this, but through my own testing and through other forums and blogs, I have received many others who agree these no longer work for W10 app.

See these blog posts for some more details into W10 app. Most references to the email background issues is in the comments section.

http://freshinbox.com/blog/the-outlook-team-reaches-out/

https://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2015/04/11/an-email-developers-first-look-at-the-outlook-mail-app-in-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks a lot, gonna look at it now, btw, do you know if all this methods are also compatible with the outlook office version?

Comment: the desktop versions of Outlook still work properly (from what I have seen) it is only the default app that is providing issues.

Comment: You mean that the op code should work on destop outlook versions??
I

Comment: To my knowledge. I did not look through it too closely, but looks right. Can also use "backgrounds.cm" to get VML code for background image in Outlook if needed.

Comment: I tried backgrounds.cm and didnt make it work in w10 mail app. After reafing jame's blog seems like the v:fill is no longer supported.

Comment: correct no back ground or button VML will work.  The backgrounds.cm was for reference for the desktop Outlook clients, not w10 app.